# Laravel Performance Problems with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel

Was working on a Laravel 4.2 app.  Decided to update to the latest stable 5.1.15.  Was still on an old version of homestead, so figured I'd update that too.

Went through all the upgrade steps etc... Got it up and running, but the homepage, which has 304 queries according to laravel debug bar (runs through a lengthy table of USA zip codes), takes **80-120 seconds to load**.  It previously took 2-3 seconds on 4.2 and homestead vagrant box 1.6.

Troubleshooting for a day, I've noticed the big difference between homestead vagrant box versions 0.2.0 and 0.2.1, for which the update from mysql 5.5 to 5.6 seems to be the main difference.

To copy the database, I've just been using Sequel Pro export and import
on the various homestead vagrant boxes.

At any rate, same code on both the old app (laravel 4.2) and new app (laravel 5.1.15) work great on any homestead vagrant boxes 0.2.0 and below, and takes upwards of a minute to load homepage on homestead vagrant box 0.2.1+.

Is there something I need to do with MySQL 5.6 to optimize performance?

Comment: Try to rebuild your indexes. Also check that you have indexed things correctly, so where you query `WHERE column = ?` then column should have an index?

Comment: It would be nice if You give these part of code where it does 304 queries.

Comment: Your homepage with 304 queries actually reminds me of a story that I once read: https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/TutorialCachingStory ;-)

Comment: of course if a lengthy table of USA zip codes does not change often so You may cache them, You'll gain performance, You'll cut out many of queries.

Comment: I'm all for caching, or even making the page static if I have to, but am more concerned about figuring out the difference between MySQL 5.5 & 5.6 so I can watch out for other problems.

Comment: I know it's dumb question, but: is it in production mode? (:

Comment: also try to manualy change table engine to MyISAM

Comment: _also try to manualy change table engine to MyISAM_???? really???

Answer (score 1):

You've tried to turn performance_schema off?

In your my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = off
```

This will save (a lot) of RAM and mysql performance.